# Define an invertible matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to define a matrix $Q_hat$. This matrix is supposed to be invertible. But apart from that, all the entries are supposed to be variables, so I can choose the entries of the matrix freely. However $Q_hat$ has to be invertible, as I said, and it is supposed to have $s-1$ rows and columns respectively. The number $s$ is supposed to be a variable as well - so the amount of rows/columns is not yet clear either.

What should I do?

I tried the following:

```
s = 5
Q_hat = np.array([[None]*(s-1)]*(s-1))
P1 = np.array([[None]*(s-1)]*(s-1))
E1 = P1*Q_hat
E1 = np.identity(s)
print(Q_hat)
```

and

```
s = 5
Q_hat = np.array([[random.randint(1,10)]*(s-1)]*(s-1))
P1 = np.array([[random.randint(1,10)]*(s-1)]*(s-1))
E1 = P1*Q_hat
E1 = np.identity(s-1)
print(Q_hat)
```

My aim was to define an other matrix $P1$ so that $Q_hat * P1 = np.identity(s-1)$. My hope was that by doing this I would show that the invertible matrix exists in the first place. But I reckon that my trouble was that I would have to do it "beforehand" - I do not think that it is possible to just define another matrix and the claim afterwards that it is the inverse.
What should I do instead? Remember, that it can be any sort of (s-1)x(s-1)-Matrix its coefficients I can choose freely - barring the fact that the matrix has to be invertible.

On Stackoverflow I just found questions about how to invert a matrix, rather than how to define an invertible matrix in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

Do you just have to create any invertible matrix? Create the identity matrix which is guaranteed to be invertible.

Or do you need to create a "random" invertible matrix?  In that case, I would just create a matrix of the appropriate size with random elements, and if its determinate is zero, throw it out and try again.  The odds that a matrix picked at random is not invertible is vanishingly small.